# I have an existing SUMX function that I would like to apply an ALLSELECTED on....please advise

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

```
SUMX(
    FILTER(
    Title, 
    Title[ASIN] = Title[ASIN]
        && Title[Name] = Title[Name]
    ),
    Title[sold_count]
)
```

the above formula work to aggregate ASIN and Name by sold count. I wanted to also add this evaluation with ALLSELECED(so that slicers would apply to result for users), is this possible?

Comment: Slicers will apply to the results of the calculation as is.  ALLSELECTED would be used to remove filters in the current filter context (or visual).  Do you have an example of what's not working and how you want it to work?

Comment: I have an instance where the report has many other values, a user wanted the functionality to apply based on filters selected. The above formula does work but I was just wondering if the Title[Name] exists as a slicer as well then could the selection by users be applied to the formula?

Comment: Yes, the slicer should still affect the filter of the formula.  Also, I'm not clear on what the formula should be doing - it looks like the FILTER on the sales table would not actually filter anything.  It should be functionally equivalent to `[sold_count]`.  You might compare the results of the two

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put both of your filter arguments into slicer, and filter them by slicer-selected input: Then please use this code:

```
YourDAXCode =
VAR PickATitleName =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Title[Name] )
VAR PickAASIN =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Title[ASIN] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( Title, Title[ASIN] = PickAASIN && Title[Name] = PickATitleName ),
        Title[sold_count]
    )
```